# Accessing two rows using index when index datatype is Datetime in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a pandas Dataframe df1 as below

```
print(df1)
    W  X  Y  Z
A -10 -9 -8 -7
B  -6 -5 -4 -3
C  -2 -1  0  1
D   2  3  4  5
E   6  7  8  9
```

And I tried to access “A” and “B” as below

```
print (df1.loc[['A','B'], :])

    W  X  Y  Z
A -10 -9 -8 -7
B  -6 -5 -4 -3
```

same way i have sales dataframe as below where datatype of Date is Datetime;

```
print(sales.head())
                 Col1    Col2        Col3        Col4        Col5        Col6
Date                                                                          
2015-01-02    0.000559  0.002772   0.002992   -0.001438  -0.002320   -0.002189
2015-01-05   -0.029050 -0.031515  -0.031223   -0.031045  -0.031258   -0.027422
2015-01-06   -0.029919 -0.035205  -0.020229   -0.025929  -0.028800   -0.020865
2015-01-07    0.004745  0.009270   0.014903    0.001526   0.014278    0.005951
2015-01-08    0.020661  0.015048   0.015965    0.022346   0.014889    0.022137
```

However when I have a Dataframe where index datatype is Datetime Then its error;

```
Print(sales.loc[['2015-01-02','2015-01-08'], :])

KeyError: "None of [Index(['2015-01-02', '2015-01-08'], dtype='object', name='Date')] are in the [index]"
```

**Can’t we select particular rows using index when index datatype is Datetime ?**

Please suggest.

Comment: worked fine when i did a clipboard read of ur data. YOBEN's solution provides a safe and sane alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can correct your filter by add `pd.to_datetime` make the type same:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-02','2015-01-08']), :]
                Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5      Col6
2015-01-02  0.000559  0.002772  0.002992 -0.001438 -0.002320 -0.002189
2015-01-08  0.020661  0.015048  0.015965  0.022346  0.014889  0.022137
```